# Finding the source of a CSS file compiled from SASS

Tags: css, sass

The project I am working on has a complicated stylesheet library with multiple vendor libraries of scss and many files and folders filled with scss files that are compiled into a single css file.

When I want to make a simple change to the css, I have to spend alot of time searching through the file structure for the source scss file. Normally I would just use the developer tools in the browser, but this only shows what the css file looks like, and most of the time the classes are created from multiple sources and override each other, so the scss does not look like the css in the end.

Is there an easy way to find the source of css compiled from scss?

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else ends up here, to use source maps in Chrome for Sass, you need to use the `--sourcemap` flag to generate them first!

```
sass --watch --sourcemap --debug-in sass/screen.scss:screen.css
```

More info: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/tips-and-tricks#debugging-sass

And using the `--debug-info` flag sets up the scss to read by FireSass.