# Find the class name in source SCSS file which gets compiled into a single CSS file in browser

Tags: html, css, angularjs, sass, single-page-application

I have a application which uses app.css in index.html. This app.css is the output css file from multiple SCSS files.
While inspecting an element to find css of that element, how can I know from which SCSS file is that style from?

Comment: You can't, unless the SCSS files are compiled, on the fly, server side.

Comment: Close if not precise duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14782319/finding-the-source-of-a-css-file-compiled-from-sass?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[SASS Source Mapping](http://thesassway.com/intermediate/using-source-maps-with-sass)**. This will let you display the exact `.scss` file in your browser inspector.

Adding a flag to Sass's command line tool:

> $ sass sass/screen.scss:stylesheets/screen.css --sourcemap

If you look in your output folder after running that command, you'll notice that a comment has been added to the end of the generated CSS file:

```
/*# sourceMappingURL=screen.css.map */
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

As you've shown no code, i'll assume... you're using compass to compile? In this case you can use the ruby to sourcemap your files for you.

This can be done like so:

```
# Enable CSS source maps for development
sourcemap = true
```

This can be added to your rubyfile.

If you're using gulp or grunt you can use:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-concat-sourcemap
or 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-concat-sourcemap

or if you're using sass:

http://thesassway.com/intermediate/using-source-maps-with-sass